# Ruby/OpenSSL: decipher final throwsOpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError, padding = 0 won't solve it

Tags: ruby, encoding, openssl, cryptography

I ciphered `data` strings with:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.key = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest password
iv = cipher.random_iv
encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final

base64_iv = Base64.encode64 iv
base64_encrypted = Base64.encode64  encrypted

puts base64_iv
puts base64_encrypted
File.write  enc_iv_base64_filename, base64_iv
File.write  encrypted_base64_filename, base64_encrypted
```

And I normally decipher with this procedure:

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
decipher.decrypt
# decipher.padding = 0
decipher.key = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest password
decipher.iv = Base64.decode64 (File.read base64_iv)
plain = decipher.update(Base64.decode64(File.read base64_encrypted)) + decipher.final
```

It has always worked for all the  values I tried with `data` containing small strings.

Now I am trying it with a string having the contents of ~500MB file, mostly composed of "readable" chars (A curious fact is that, having 1100MB of free memory wasn't enough, but after adding 2G swap did the work; not important for this question =) ). The file was decrypted, uploaded to a server, and downloaded again. By trying to decrypt it, it's throwing this exception:

```
:in `final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
```

I, then, commented out:

```
decipher.padding = 0
```

The decryption goes to the end -- which shows that the decryption parameters, like `iv`, `key` and so on are correct -- however, the data is completely unreadable -- suggesting that I am having a problem with encoding. Could the padding have changed the way the `data` string will be decoded? Can anyone affirm that the file could  only be corrupted during transmission? What's the answer to the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that any `key` will decipher a cipher, but only the correct `key` will decipher to something (similar) to the original stream.

In my case I was using a bad `password`  which had invisible characters. The `password` had been previously deciphered by the same procedure. Without `padding = 0`  the password used to be correctly generated. After adding `padding = 0`, some padding was added to the output.  Note that `puts` won't print the "invisible" chars, but `p` will.

It still remains a doubt on how to ensure that the deciphered text was the original ciphered text. however, the question itself is answered.

Comment: As for the last doubt: use an authenticated cipher such as GCM or a separate MAC such as HMAC (in the last case, don't forget to MAC the IV!).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I was thinking about add something `<length>L</length>` to the begin of the stream. Then I could use `padding = 0`, and, when deciphering I could discard the chars exceeding `L`. Don't you think I can just patch my procedure instead? Do you see any danger on that?